# SIP телефония с кодом +1

Tags: sip

Есть ли программа SIP где можно прописать код страны,например если я кликаю на американский номер без кода +1 (например (773)245-54-67), чтобы программа понимала что это америка?

Comment: А как вы определяте, что это номер американский?

Comment: Мы набираем номера с американского сайта, а там все номера без +1.